# Абстрактные свойства C#, ошибка или особенность?

Tags: c#

Исходные условия:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    int SomeProperty { get; }
}

abstract class SomeClass
{
    public abstract int AnotherProperty { get; }
}

class InheritedClass : SomeClass, ISomeInterface
{

    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public override int AnotherProperty  { get; set; }//Ошибка
}
```

Почему возникает ошибка при реализации абстрактного свойства в классе-наследнике, если добавить не заявленный в абстрактном свойстве геттер или сеттер? И почему нет ошибки для свойства объявленного в интерфейсе при тех же условиях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения интерфейсов, все правильно. Свойство представляет из себя пару методов. В интерфейсе, мы обязываем класс, реализующий наш интерфейс реализовать  свойство с указанным аксессором, при этом не накладывая ни каких условий на наличие либо отсутствие второго аксессора.

С абстрактным классом немного сложнее. При реализации абстрактного свойства мы обязаны указать перед таким свойством ключевое слово `override`, указывающее компилятору, что свойство было объявлено в базовом классе.

> Синтаксис не позволяет указать `override` для одного конкретного
>   аксессора, а только для всего свойства целиком, поэтому необъявленый в
>   базовом классе аксессор, тоже получает метку `override`, но
>   переопределить его нельзя,  так как он отсутствует в базовом классе.

Таким образом имеем противоречие: с одной стороны, мы пытаемся добавить новый метод в класс наследник, что не должно вызывать каких либо проблем, с другой, следуя синтаксису языка, пытаемся переопределить несуществующий метод, что вполне закономерно вызывает ошибку компиляции.

Вопрос почему сделано именно так, оставлю на совести разработчиков спецификации языка, в любом случае вряд ли это исправят в ближайшем будущем, если вообще исправят, поэтому проще считать это "особенностью" языка и просто знать о ней.

**Как обойти проблему**

Одно из возможных решений обхода данной "особенности":

```
abstract class SomeClass
{
    public int AnotherProperty 
    { 
        get { return GetAnotherProperty(); }  
    }
    protected abstract int GetAnotherProperty();
}

class InheritedClass : SomeClass
{
    public new int AnotherProperty  { get; set; }
    protected override int GetAnotherProperty() 
    { 
        return AnotherProperty; 
    }
}
```

Другой вариант - вынести свойство в отдельный интерфейс и реализовать его в производном классе, тогда проблема решается вроде бы сама собой, но иногда такое решение не приемлемо, например если в абстрактном классе есть реализованные методы использующие данное свойство.

Ну и радикальный вариант - отказ от свойства как такового, и возврат к классическим методам `GetXXX()` и `SetXXX(value)`, этот вариант возможен абсолютно в любых условиях и не вызывает проблем ни в интерфейсах, ни в абстрактных классах, но ухудшает читабельность кода, хотя это конечно на любителя, в Java например, это единственный возможный вариант, если за последнее время в ней ни чего кардинально не поменялось.

Comment: Какой-то странный, на мой непросвещенный взгляд, способ обхода. Исходная позиция: мы хотим унаследовать свойство с переопределением. Результат обходного маневра: мы наследуем метод с переопределением, а про свойство, которое нам как раз таки нужно было, мы не должны забыть и сами его создать.

Comment: @Bulson в данном случае выбора практически нет, просто переопределить такое свойство не выйдет, почему уже написал. Так что перекрытие вполне подходит если нужно сохранить именно свойство.

Comment: @rdorn по мне так логично, вы берете реализацию из абстрактного класса и её переопределяете, даже не переопределяете а кардинально меняете, реализацию относительно филда (добавляете setter).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda в том то и дело что не реализацию, посмотрите исходный вариант. Свойство заявлено абстрактным, реализации там быть не может, это такой же контракт как и интерфейс. И опять же, свойства - чисто синтаксическая конструкция, сахар так сказать, для сокращения объема кода. А собственно поля здесь вообще ни при чем, они наследуются как есть и переопределению не подлежат. А тут да, приходится уйти от переопределения и использовать перекрытие, для сохранения внешней идентичности, да при этом меняется внутренний механизм